# Check for length not working right

Tags: javascript

no idea why but this does not work right

```
var ddlCar = document.getElementById('<%=ddlCar.ClientID %>');
var carname_dropdown = ddlCar.options[ddlCar.selectedIndex].text;

if (!carid.length && (carname_drop).length)
    carname = carname_drop;
```

So if cariid is invalid and carname_drop is valid, use (set) carname to carname_drop

I know carid is set to a valid number.  I know that carname_drop has a valid number.  So this if statement should skip the setting of canname based on the fact that carid is indeed valid and has a length (a value).

Comment: you declare `carname_dropdown` but then use `carname_drop`.

Comment: deleting this, found it.

Comment: What about working left?

Answer (score 1):

Can be the variable name **carname_dropdown** X **carname_drop** ?

Answer (score 0):

Make it read:

```
if (!carid.length && carname_dropdown.length)
```

This assumes that carid is a valid object; its creation is not shown in your code.